# SSIS ExecuteTask will provide benefit when update SQL Server Large Table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis

For a Migration like task, we are trying to update the string value (hash value) in a table with 15 million rows based on a table with 1 million rows.

Query: 
update a
set col b = b.col2
from tbl1 a
join tbl2 b on a.col1 = b.col1

Indexes are properly set.
For this update, If we use SSIS, will it provide benefits?

Thanks!

Comment: The only benefit that SSIS will bring to this is if you want to automate the task as a part of your overall migration. Or, are you thinking you want to move this to a process that updates some rows rather than all rows at once?

Comment: I would just like to know would it bring any performance benefit? And it is one time update only.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the best performance running the query as TSQL.  SSIS will add no benefit in this case.